# Rails - do action and http verb have to match?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A custom action `export_file` is defined in routes.rb:

```
   resource :payment_requests do
      collection do
        get :export_file
      end
   end
```

In a `form_tag`, can we use `method: put` for export_file even though the `export_file` is a `get`?

```
<%= form_tag export_file_payment_requests_path(format: 'csv'), method: :put do %>
   ......
  <%= submit_tag 'CSV' %>
<% end %>
```

It seems OK to use `put` method for `get` action according to http document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, yes that's fine - you absolutely can send a `PUT` request from a form in Rails.

However, if you specify a route in your `routes.rb` file as being a `get` request, it will only ever match it using the HTTP GET verb.

Take a look at the output from `rake routes`:

```
               Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                                                  Controller#Action
 api_v1_search_simple GET      /api/v1/search/simple(.:format)                                              api/v1/search#simple
     new_user_session GET      /auth/login(.:format)                                                        devise/sessions#new
         user_session POST     /auth/login(.:format)                                                        devise/sessions#create
 destroy_user_session DELETE   /auth/logout(.:format)                                                       devise/sessions#destroy
        user_password POST     /auth/password(.:format)                                                     devise/passwords#create
    new_user_password GET      /auth/password/new(.:format)                                                 devise/passwords#new
   edit_user_password GET      /auth/password/edit(.:format)                                                devise/passwords#edit
                      PATCH    /auth/password(.:format)                                                     devise/passwords#update
                      PUT      /auth/password(.:format)                                                     devise/passwords#update
    user_confirmation POST     /auth/confirmation(.:format)                                                 devise/confirmations#create
new_user_confirmation GET      /auth/confirmation/new(.:format)                                             devise/confirmations#new
                      GET      /auth/confirmation(.:format)                                                 devise/confirmations#show
                 root GET      /                                                                            dashboards#show
```

You see how it lists the `Verb` it will match against?

If you want to send a `PUT` request and have rails match it against a particular controller and action, then you should specify it as a `put` request in your `routes.rb` file.

You do have the option of using the `match` wildcard to define a route, but that is generally considered a bad thing to do, since it opens up your application for misuse.

This guide is really useful: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

If you read [section 3.7](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints), you'll see that you can use the `match` keyword along with the `via` attribute to restrict what verbs your route should match against. Such as this:

```
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: [:get, :post]
```

You could use a route like that to match against both `GET` and `PUT` if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  `However, if you specify a route in your routes.rb file as being a get request, it will only ever match it using the HTTP GET verb.` - does it mean that the action (declared as `get` in routes.rb) will always be fulfilled with http GET no matter what in `method:`?

Comment: If action in routes.rb and method: do not match, then rails routing will not be done right. This is what we found in our testing. So in practical, they should match.

Comment: I think you're confusing things slightly. The `action` within the controller can have any name you like. In your case it is `export_file`. Because you're defining that route with the `get` keyword, Rails will only match it if the request is a `GET` request.